# How to embed text inside image?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I want to embed username inside image before showing that image to the user.
Like I have an image file and now I want to put the user name inside image it's like embedding not just putting text. So that text became actual part of image ?
Can you guys suggest me a way out and output schould be a base64 file so I can stream data over api .
Thank you.

Comment: You could load your image in a hidden canvas, print the username ontop of it, and then extract the canvas image. However that calculation would be clientside, not sure if that fits for your purpose (therefore the client will still be able to extract the original, if he has some basic tech knowledge). You can search for loading image to canvas.

Comment: I mean... that would require Photoshop or some other editing software.  Nothing you do within the frameworks of web dev tech stack (HTML/CSS/JS) will actually alter the image.  You can overlay text within the image but you aren't going to fundamentally change the image without editing it directly in editing software.

Comment: @Not true, we can alter an image with some text with javascript.

Comment: Not without calling a separate watermarking library with JS, no.

Comment: In Node you'll want to use a library like [jimp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp). Personally, I would use PHP for this. It's faster at processing images, and it should work [out of the box](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not specify what software your API server is running so I wrote [this](https://github.com/GirkovArpa/watermark) for your client-side watermarking needs.  It only works for images without transparency.

It's an implementation of LSB (least significant bit) encoding.

> index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="index.js"></script>

<body>
</body>
<script>
  (async () => {
    const base64 = `data:image/png;base64,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`;
    const watermark = await createWatermark(base64, 'John Doe');

    const image = new Image();
    image.src = watermark;
    document.body.appendChild(image); // displays watermarked image on screen

    const hiddenText = await readWatermark(watermark, 8);
    console.log(hiddenText); // John Doe
  })();
</script>

</html>
```

> index.js

```js
function stringToBits(string) {
  return string.split('')
    .map(char => char.charCodeAt(0))
    .map(int => (int).toString(2).padStart(8, '0').split(''))
    .flat()
    .map(n => +n);
}

function bitsToString(bits) {
  bits = [...bits.map(n => getBit(n, 0))];
  return String.fromCharCode(...Array(Math.ceil(bits.length / 8))
    .fill()
    .map(() => bits.splice(0, 8))
    .map(arr => parseInt(arr.join(''), 2)));
}

function setBit(number, bitPosition, sign) {
  if (sign) return number | (1 << bitPosition);
  const mask = ~(1 << bitPosition);
  return number & mask;
}


function getBit(number, bitPosition) {
  return (number & (1 << bitPosition)) === 0 ? 0 : 1;
}

function createWatermark(imageAsBase64, text) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const image = new Image();
    image.src = imageAsBase64;
    image.onload = () => {
      const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.width = image.width;
      canvas.height = image.height;
      const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
      const imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      const bits = stringToBits(text);
      for (let i = 0; i < text.length * 8; i += 4) {
        imageData.data[i] = setBit(imageData.data[i], 0, bits[i]);
        imageData.data[i + 1] = setBit(imageData.data[i + 1], 0, bits[i + 1]);
        imageData.data[i + 2] = setBit(imageData.data[i + 2], 0, bits[i + 2]);
        imageData.data[i + 3] = setBit(imageData.data[i + 3], 0, bits[i + 3]);
      }
      context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
      resolve(canvas.toDataURL());
    }
  });
}

function readWatermark(base64, textLength) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const image = new Image();
    image.src = base64;
    image.onload = () => {
      const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.width = image.width;
      canvas.height = image.height;
      const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
      const imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      const bits = imageData.data.slice(0, textLength * 8);
      resolve(bitsToString(bits));
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: can you please explain I don't want to just put code inside and yes I want to do it client side no problem if user see the actual image. What set bit and get bit functions are doing and can't we just do it like making an image inside canvas and then putting text over image and then converting the whole canvas a base64 image with the help of toDataURL function.

Comment: I thought you wanted the text to be invisibly embedded in the image.  You want it visible and overlaid on top?

Comment: yes, @GrikovArpa, I wanted it with the image so I can ship it with image over API nothing else fancy can you suggest a way out is my thinking process is right can I do that way .....

Comment: yes, @GrikovArpa, I wanted it with the image so I can ship it with image over API nothing else fancy can you suggest a way out is my thinking process is right can I do that way .....

Comment: It's as simple as writing `context.fillText(text, 0, 0)` immediately after `context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);`.

Comment: Please go to the link and see the image                                                                                                                   https://ibb.co/N95XxG8                                                                                                                   You see the text  "Kumar" and text letter "P" which are dynamically put inside the image to show result on how to do this. Thank You I really want to learn this.

Comment: I posted the solution [here](https://github.com/GirkovArpa/text-on-image).